# Is it safe to delete an object having a dynamically allocated block using delete keyword

Tags: c++, memory-management

This question may sound too simple to some guys, but I am trying to understand what happens if I delete an object having a dynamically allocated block using **delete keyword**

Calling a delete will do 2 things, first call the destructor and then release the memory.
If delete is releasing the object memory then will it also release the dynamic allocated memory or would I have to write a block of code in destructor to actually release the memory block safely.

Also if objects are allocated memory in heap then what other things other than member variables will take up the memory allocated to the object.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have something like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   int* block;

   Foo()
   {
       block = new int[10];
   }

private:
   Foo(const Foo&);
   Foo& operator =(const Foo&);
};
```

And subsequently do this:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo;
delete foo;
```

Then yes, you're leaking memory. The dynamic block in your Foo object is never released. You can address this with a destructor that releases it. (of source, you need to declare the destructor in the class declaration as well):

```
Foo::~Foo()
{
    delete [] block;
}
```

I would advise you to do two things

1. Count the delete's and the new's. if they're not the same, thats generally a problem.
2. Read this [informative document](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C++.pdf) on dynamic pointer and memory usage with C++.

Following #2, btw, might give you an object that looks similar to this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   std::array<int,10> block;

   Foo() // note: default-construction of `block`
   {
   }

   // note: default *destructor* will clean up member variables
   //  by firing their destructors for you. in this case the destructor
   //  for our 'block' member is a std::array that knows how to self-clean.

   // note: we no longer have to hide or implement copy construction and
   //  assignment operator functionality. The default implementation of 
   //  these properly member-copy and member-assign respectively.
};
```

And a usage (one of many possibilities) like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo);
```

Please regard the notes in the source of the last example. There is a *tremendous* weight lifted off your memory-management shoulders by using classes that practice self-managed members. In lifting that weight, so too goes the per-chance likelihood of introducing bugs related to it, like memory leaks, shallow-copy perils, etc.

Comment: @WhozCraig...Question...When does that destructor gets called? As soon as it encounters `}` that is the end of the block?

Comment: @noleptr In the case of a dynamic allocation, the destructor execution is part of the delete operation on the referenced pointer prior to the memory being returned to the memory management system. This allows you to access your object's members (and in this case clean them up). For automatic variables (`Foo foo;`) the destructors are fired when leaving the scope in which the object is declared. The alternative I posted practices [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and I would suggest you consider it as a programming guideline for future projects.

Answer (score 1):

The memory freed when you call `delete` is just that occupied by the object itself. The object occupies a number of contiguous bytes, and those are released on `delete`.  `sizeof(MyType)` will show you how many bytes that is. And *nothing* else is released by `delete`. Everything else is released by the destructor (or by the destructor of individual member objects)

Answer (score 1):

Working with a dynamically allocated block you need to call delete[].

For example:

```
class C
{
    //some members
public:
    C() {...}
    ~C() {...} 
    // some methods
};

int main()
{
C * arr = new C[10]; // Dynamically allocated memory

// some code using arr . . .

delete[] arr; // Calling ~C() for each C element in arr and then releasing the dynamically alloacted memory on the heap pointed by arr.
}
```

But, if in addition you have a memeber pointer that was dynamically allocated, you will need to delete it in the destructor of the object:

```
C::C()
: memberArray(new int[10]) {  }

C::~C()
{
   delete[] memberArray;
   memberArray = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A use of the destructor is that you call the `delete` statements for each pointer attributes it contains.
If for example I have a class "car" which has an attribute "tire", which would be a pointer, you would need to delete this attribute in the car's destructor.

Answer (score 0):

No, the allocated memory will not be released.

When an object which allocated dynamic memory and assigned it to a pointer is deleted, only the pointer will be released, not the data it points to. When an object allocated memory, you **must** manually call a delete for that data in its destructor, or make sure that it is deleted by some other object which got a pointer to that data.

Deleting it automatically would be impossible, because the object could have passed the allocated data to another object which still needs it after the allocating object was deleted.